# Duplicate sales order grid to custom admin page

Tags: magento2, module, api, admin-panel, order-grid

I need to copy the **sales_order_grid table** to a **custom admin page**. Is there a way to do so using **Magento's API**?

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard ui grid in custom layout, like:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <uiComponent name="sales_order_grid"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Superb It's working!

Comment: how to edit a mass action options in duplicate sales_order_grid

Comment: If I want to add the custom column and add the data into the columns by using the API How can I achieve this

Comment: @RanaZain, to do this you can simply update the orders grid listing in your module by creating a file `view/adminhtml/ui_comComponent/sales_order_grid.xml`. But all changes will be visible in both places: in the custom controller with the orders grid and in the regular sales orders grid.

Comment: I want to replicate the gird and then add custom columns in it and fetch data from the API